# google contacts sync

Tags: contacts, gmail

I have 2 Samsung Android phones and both are synced with 1 gmail account. now the issue i am facing is:

1. The number of contacts restored on both the phones is different. ie. for example I have total 500 contacts stored on gmail one of my phone is showing 490 contacts and the other is showing 495 contacts, where as in total I have 500 contacts.
2. Sometimes when I add contact to one of my phones it automatically adds the contact on phone memory & google contacts on the other phone instead of google contacts only. I want to store to google contacts only and not phone memory as it slows down my phone.

What could be wrong here, and how can I fix it?